# Number of Lattice Points In A Circle

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, algebraic-geometry, analytic-geometry

This is a slightly different question than others on this topic. For the equation $x^2+y^2 \leq r$ where $r$ can be any integer and not just a perfect square, when is the number of lattice points that fall under this region odd, and when is it even? What if the region was $x^2+y^2 < r$?

I would prefer a solution with intermediate level counting, as this problem was one from a competition of similar level. Also, if you're able to find a general formula for the exact number of lattice points, that would be greatly appreciated as well.

Comment: always odd  because there is just one way to express $0 = 0^2 + 0^2$  while any positive number has count divisible by $4$

Comment: You have written that you're looking for a solution with "intermediate level counting", but you're put this in the algebraic-geometry tag, where problems "... typically involve techniques of abstract algebra or complex-analytic methods," and which "... should not be used for elementary problems which involve both algebra and geometry." (cf [the tag info](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/algebraic-geometry/info)). This is a bit of a mismatch - which aligns more closely with your intentions? (Please watch out for tag usage guidance in the future to avoid this problem.)

Comment: Are you already aware of what is known when r is a perfect square : https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssCircleProblem.html ?

Comment: [sum of 2 squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem)